My son disturbed after no one shared a snack. How do I teach him lesson from this?
My son is 8yo, today at school everyone was exchanging sweets, he didn't mention it to us so we never knew it was a day of exchanging sweets. He felt heartbroken as no one is the class shared with him. Is it concerning and damaging as well. I told him that

we cannot expect people to share, if you share that doesn't mean someone else is having same values. Mom, dad and siblings are best friends as He also complain about not having friends.

He started his schooling in private school, due to finance, I took him out after year 2 but the mindset of private vs pupuil is huge! But did I tell my son right thing?
My second one is very jolly and he started in public school, today he felt down and he tells me someone call him dumb in class, I would talk to teacher but feel like they are not settling in or we as a parent are feeling too much?

Did he have sweets to share with others?

@Arno no he didn’t as he forgot to tell us

I think it is quite normal that since your son was not contributing to the sweet exchange, he was not receiving either. If he already had some good friends in the class, if some of the other children was particularly empathetic or if he was recognized as a charity case, it may have been different. But without such factors, it is likely he was perceived as a freeloader and thus excluded.
The appropriate post mortem here is to observe that the issue was caused by his behaviour (not by his person), and to identify what to do better next time: He needs to tell you about such things in advance, so that you can provide him with sweets, or assist him in buying some with his allowance, or assist him in making some.
I think what you told him was a bad way to handle the situation. While it is true that you cannot rely on everyone reciprocating, that's unrelated to the situation here. He wasn't sharing stuff himself!
More generally, friends and parents are very distinct social roles. If your son doesn't have any friends, he needs to make some, not rely on you and his mother to compensate. This episode doesn't indicate that his classmates aren't reasonable candidates for him to make friends with, but if that doesn't work out he'll have to look for friends elsewhere (eg via some hobby/sports group).

I'm sure it was heartbreaking hearing your child share his disappointment with the sweets sharing experience.  Perhaps it would be help to start teaching him about being a member of a community and understanding how to build relationships by giving and then also receiving.  Also, I think it is good to let him know that the fact other children didn't share with him is not a reflection of them being unwilling to be friends with him.  Because this was an "event" and there were guidelines provided, the children were just doing what they were told were the rules.
As a parent, it's also hard to keep track of all these school events.  At age 8, it's often hard for them to remember everything they're told and pass on that information to parents.  Maybe it can also be good for you to reach out to the teacher to suggest that notes be sent home if there are school events like this in the future so all parents can help their kids participate.  I'm confident your child is not the only one who felt left out and increased participation would benefit all kids, giving your son a chance to engage more with his peers.
